# Inflate view into DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a little problem with my `DialogFragment.`, a custom one I wrote for my app.

In this fragment I have one button which must start showing custom view which are inflated to root frame layout of my app.

Could you please tell me how can I do this?

Comment: Could you please be a little more specific? Your question is a bit unclear. If you could show us some of your code, and what you've tried so far..I'm sure the guys here would have an easier time helping you out

Comment: SO basically what I understand is that you want to show a custom view only when a button is pressed and without that the view will be hidden ??

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you correctly, you want to display your view only when the button is pressed.
So, you need to use the `android:visibility` attribute here and use either `GONE` or `INVISIBLE` values.

Then when the button is pressed, retrieve an instance of the custom view, and then set the value to `VISIBLE` using the `setVisibility()` method.

Comment: Yes, but this view are inflated to root frame. And my dialogFragment are created over that view. I use visibility options now. But my custom view are already inflated to another fragment by default.